# How to check is a user has permission to database query?

Tags: node.js, database, security, authentication, web

Lets say I have a website where car dealerships manage their automobile inventory. Each car dealership has its own `company_id`, and their staff members use staff accounts with a `staff_id`.

When a staff member is at the page `http://sellcarsfaster.com/inventory/car/jdksf9843`
they should see their company's car with the id `jdksf9843`. If they copy this url and send it to a fellow staff member, that other staff should be able to view the car. However, if the url is sent to a non-staff member, that user can NOT view the car. The car should only be accessible to staff members of that car dealership.

Taking it one step further, how can I check for permissions across a large variety of possible database queries for a variety of assets with a variety of relationships? Such as below:

`http://sellcarsfaster.com/inventory/car/jdksf9843/tires/93sl9843`
`http://sellcarsfaster.com/insurance/2djlasd8`
`http://sellcarsfaster.com/history/event/8o4jsdfj`

Is there a best practice for checking view permissions in an app such as this? What should be done in the backend? Will I have to do computationally-heavy database queries to authenticate? Do I have to write custom authentication functions for each database query? Is it secure to authenticate based off `staff_id` or `company_id`?

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

P.S.
I currently have JSON Web Token authentication in my backend, but it does not prevent staff members of differing companies from seeing eachothers inventory with just the url.

Using NodeJS and Postgres with AWS Cognito for user authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use AWS Cognito and NodeJS backend exposed through API Gateway then you can directly authorize the endpoints with IAM policies. The setup would be in summary as follows.

- Setup Cognito Userpools and integrate it with your NodeJS App
- Setup AWS API Gateway as a proxy to your NodeJS server and configure each route path to it.
- Configure API Gateway to use IAM authorizer.
- Using Cognito User Groups Feature, you can attach IAM Roles (Policies inside) where each group of users has access to the respective endpoints granted by IAM policies.
- For secure you NodeJS Server from direct access (Only allowing access through API Gateway) you can use API Gateway Client Certificates or use a different authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

JSON web tokens are perfect for your scenario. You can store the company ID in the token. Then everyone can use the same URL. In the backend you authenticate their token, if it passes that means the token hasn't been altered.

**The fact that the token was authenticated means the companyID was the one you provided, and is therefore legit. **

Grab the company ID from the token and the car ID from the URL. You should have all the info to craft a SQL query that reads something like SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE 'carID'=x AND 'companyID'=y;

If database response is empty, handle as you see fit.

Comment: The issue is that all these different queries do not have access to a `company_id` in their table. Eg. `tire` will not have a `company_id`, but `car` will have `company_id`